# Having to sometimes click twice on checkbox data-toggle="buttons"

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

any help would be great :) I am wanting to just have a toggle on/off, I am just about there I think, but sometimes I have to click twice on the button(s) and sometimes I don't?

I could probably live with it, but it's bugging me that I can't figure it out - quite new to the whole Ajax post malarky.

I am using Bootstrap 3, using chrome primarily

Thanks

My HTML - table (built from DB)

```
    <table class="table">
    <?php
    /* DB STUFF */
    if($myquery->rowCount()>0) {
        while ($row = $myquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php 
                    $reject = $row['reject']; 
                    if($reject == 1) { 
                        ?>
                    <div data-toggle="buttons">
                        <div class="switch_label btn-group" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                            <label class="btn btn-success">
                                <input id="exc_agent<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> <span id="sp<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">On</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="result_label<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> </div>
                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <div data-toggle="buttons">
                        <div class="switch_label btn-group" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                            <label class="btn btn-danger">
                                <input id="exc_agent<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> <span id="sp<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Off</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="result_label<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Script:

```
<script>
var exl_outlet_id;

$(document).on("click", ".switch_label", function() {
    exl_outlet_id = $(this).data('id');
});

$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});

$(".switch_label").find("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function() {
    var exl_status = $(this).prop('checked');
    if(exl_status == true) {
        exl_status = "1";
        $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-success");
        $(this).parent().addClass("btn-danger");
        $("#sp" + exl_outlet_id).html('Off');
    } else {
        exl_status = "0";
        $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-danger");
        $(this).parent().addClass("btn-success");
        $("#sp" + exl_outlet_id).html('On');
    }
    $.ajax ({
        url: 'meh.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"id": exl_outlet_id,
        "status": exl_status},
        success: function(data) {
            if(!data.success) {
                //$(".result_label" + exl_outlet_id).html(data);
            } else {
            }
        },
        error: function(error)
        {
            alert("Failed", "Fail to update status try again", "error");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$status = $_POST['status'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

if($status == 1) {
    $reject = 0;
    /* Update DB */
    return true;
} else {
    $reject = 1;
    /* Update DB */
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your issue may be related to that your label for the checkbox is inside your `.switch_label` div.  So it may be the case that the label is changing the checkbox, causing the change handler to fire, but the variable you are referenceing (exl_outlet_id) hasn't updated yet as the click hasn't bubbled up to the div yet.  Instead of using a global variable like that, I would **highly** recommend using `$(this).closest('.switch_label')` in your logic and grabbing it's `data('id')` that way.  Ref: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @Taplar thanks, not 100% sure on how to do it, but will take a look, cheers.